# MySQL query not responding with the name Bob

Tags: php, mysql

Ok this my seem a bit odd, but when I try to run the mysql query within the PHP code or in phpmyadmin it doesn't return anything:

```
DELETE FROM `EmployeeNames` WHERE FirstName = 'Bob'
```

But when I run the same line but with the name Billy it is fine and is deleted

```
DELETE FROM `EmployeeNames` WHERE FirstName = 'Billy'
```

Does anyone have a clue why this is happening, because I cant seem to figure it out.

Thanks

Comment: What do you get when you SELECT for Bob? (My initial stab in the dark: 'Bob' has whitespace on one end or the other.)

Comment: you can't delete users named Bob in mysql. It's a known glitch

Comment: @Uueerdo exactly what I thought but I got too impatient and just deleted my whole table and made a new one. This time Bob does delete :)

Comment: @Drew Really? or are you just trolling me

Comment: I need to download the patch. Until then, I am in Bob [nightmare land](http://pastie.org/10375257)

Comment: The curse of little Bobby Tables

Comment: Depending on how that Bob was inserted, it might have been imported with [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) - that happened to us when loading data from a csv file. Next time you can try `select FirstName, hex(FirstName), hex('Bob') from table where FirstName like '%Bob%'`

Comment: Are you sure the Bob in the database doesn't have line breaks, tabs, or spaces after or before? Try `DELETE FROM EmployeeNames WHERE trim(FirstName) = 'Bob'`

Comment: Post some data from table. Bob maybe has second name? :)

Comment: OK boiz this is no longer a problem after deleting the table and making a new one. How do I close this thing.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because there is no record with `FirstName = 'Bob'` (OR) in essence your condition `WHERE FirstName = 'Bob'` doesn't matches any record.

If you really sure that there is record with `FirstName = 'Bob'` then try doing a `select` with that condition. Probably, use `TRIM()` function before comparing in case there is space and due to which it's not matching

```
 DELETE FROM `EmployeeNames` WHERE TRIM(FirstName) = 'Bob'
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you even have any Bob's in your table?
Do a

```
SELECT * from `EmployeeNames` WHERE FirstName = 'Bob'
```

And see if anything is returned, most likely you deleted before

Comment: There is  Bob, including a bunch of other name, however when I add a new Bob that Bob works fine with the query it is just that one instance of Bob which cant be found in my whole database for some reason. So i just deleted the whole table